# Can a function that selects between two random variables increase the variance more than twofold?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, variance, random-functions

Let $X_1,X_2$ be two real-valued *zero-mean* random variables, and assume w.l.o.g. that $\text{Var}[X_1]\ge\text{Var}[X_2]$.

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\{1,2\}$ be a ``selection'' function, and define $Y=X_{f(X_1,X_2)}$ to be the selected (real-valued) random variable.

Is it possible to upper bound $\text{Var}[Y]$ as a function of $\text{Var}[X_1]$? For example,

> **Is it correct that $\text{Var}[Y]\le 2\text{Var}[X_1]$?**

Comment: No.  Counter-examples are easy if $X_1$ and $X_2$ have different means

Comment: @Henry - you're right, forgot to mention that both have zero-mean, thanks!

Comment: I found a discrete example where $\operatorname{Var}X_1<\operatorname{Var}Y<2\operatorname{Var}X_1$. Where does the factor of 2 come from in your conjecture?

Comment: @Karl - I had a similar example. I think that (maybe) for $k$ variables there should be a $k$ factor there, but am having hard times proving it even for $k=2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A_1, A_2$ be the disjoint events $\{f=1\}, \{f=2\}$.  Then we can write
$$Y = 1_{A_1} X_1 + 1_{A_2} X_2.$$
Note that
$$Y^2 = 1_{A_1} X_1^2 + 1_{A_2} X_2^2$$
Now
$$\begin{align*} \operatorname{Var}(Y) &\le E[Y^2] \\
&= E[1_{A_1} X_1^2] + E[1_{A_2} X_2^2] \\
&\le E[X_1^2] + E[X_2^2] \\
&= \operatorname{Var}(X_1) + \operatorname{Var}(X_2)  && \text{(since $E[X_1]=E[X_2]=0$)}\\
&\le 2 \operatorname{Var}(X_1).
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is true (your conjecture about constant $k$ for $k$ variables is also true), and is a consequence of law of total variance. More specifically, this is the law of total variance

$ Var(Y) = \mathbb{E}[Var(Y | F)] +Var(\mathbb{E}[Y \mid F])$

where I am denoting $f(X_1, X_2)$ as $F$.

Further simplification gives

$ Var(Y) \leq \sum_i Var(X_i \mid f = i) P(f = i)  + \mathbb{E}[X_i \mid f = i]^2 P(f = i) $

which means

$Var(Y) \leq \sum_i \mathbb{E}[ X_i^2 \mid f = i] P(f = i) $

Now, law of total probability here, coupled with the fact that $X_i^2 \geq 0$ and $X_i$ have 0 mean, gives you what you want.

EDIT to answer the comment:

$\sum_i \mathbb{E}[ X_i^2 \mid f = i] P(f = i) \leq \sum_i \mathbb{E}[ X_i^2 \mid f = i] P(f = i) + $
$\sum_{j \neq i} \mathbb{E}[ X_i^2 \mid f = j] P(f = j) = \sum_i \mathbb{E} X_i^2 = \sum_i Var(X_i) $

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Can you please explain the last transition? i.e., why $\sum_i \mathbb{E}[ X_i^2 \mid f = i] P(f = i) \le 2 Var(X_1)$?

Comment: I added something to the proof; let me know if it s not clear. I had a bug earlier so it is possible that there are others.